# How do you configure S3BotoStorage or collectstatic to upload to an s3 bucket subdirectory

Tags: django, amazon-s3

Is there a way to configure django's collectstatic command to upload to a subdirectory in an s3 bucket, rather than just the top level directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using the `S3BotoStorage` engine from `django-storages` then there's a settings variable called `AWS_LOCATION` which will set the key prefix (equivalent to subdirectory) for the S3 bucket you specify in `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`.

Note that I haven't used this with `collectstatic`, but I can't see how it wouldn't work given the separation between it and the storage engines.