# Django-storages + boto + S3 minimal credentials for collectstatic

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I am using `django-storages` with the `storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage` and have come across a strange `403` error.

My original IAM policy was quite conservative, and only included get, put, and delete for objects.

--> **This threw a 403 error**

I then gave all permissions ***except*** the permissions to delete and create buckets

--> To my surprise, ***this also threw the 403 error***

I finally gave full permissions, which I would like to avoid, and I am no longer getting the 403 error.

I have already tried providing access to both the bucket root `/` and `/*` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10884964/1287714)

My objective is to give only the permissions necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the **bucket policy** for uploading to a specific bucket, in this case `static`.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "StaticAndMediaPermissions",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAnybodyToGetBucketLocation",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCollectstaticUserToListStaticDirectory",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<collectstatic_user_arn_from_iam_user_summary>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/static"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCollectstaticUserAccessToAllObjectsInStaticDirectory",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<collectstatic_user_arn_from_iam_user_summary>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/static/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You will still need to add the IAM user policy from my other answer.

Make sure you have the `AWS_LOCATION` variable set to `/static/` in your `settings.py`. If you don't have that set, this will not work.

Sources:
* http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke
  - Walked through how to set directory-specific permissions
* https://stackoverflow.com/a/9649233/1999151
  - Clued me into using AWS_LOCATION

---

Alternatively, if you want to have separate directories for static and media files, you will need to follow the directions here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626241/1999151

and remove `AWS_LOCATION` from `settings.py`.

You will still need to add the IAM user policy from my other answer.

Then you will need to adjust the AWS bucket policy to the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "StaticAndMediaPermissions",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAnybodyToGetBucketLocation",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCollectstaticUserToListStaticAndMediaDirectories",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<collectstatic_user_arn_from_iam_user_summary>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/media"
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/static"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCollectstaticUserAccessToAllObjectsInStaticAndMediaDirectories",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<collectstatic_user_arn_from_iam_user_summary>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/media/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/static/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing, and I think I finally got it working (with a lot of Googling and a lot of other StackOverflow answers). This isn't guaranteed to be the minimal required set of permissions, but it isn't a whole lot.

Here is the **IAM policy** for the user `collectstatic` is using:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1399990928000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

That seems to be pretty straightforward.

From here, it gets more complicated. Things you need to change are marked within angle brackets. The **bucket policy** should be as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Permissions",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAnybodyToGetBucketLocation",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCollectstaticUserToListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<collectstatic_user_arn_from_iam_user_summary>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCollectstaticUserAccessToAllObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<collectstatic_user_arn_from_iam_user_summary>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

That gives the collectstatic's user *at least* the minimum required permissions.

Note that this assumes that you are dumping all of your objects directly into the root of the bucket and NOT into a directory like `static/`. I'm not entirely sure how to do that - whether I should specify the `Resource` as `arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/static/*` or whether to add a `Condition` onto `AllowCollectstaticUserAccessToAllObjects`.

Sources that helped me:

- http://blog.iambob.me/the-super-stupid-idiots-guide-to-getting-started-with-django-pipeline-and-s3/

  - Helped me get started with S3 configuration
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10884964

  - Need to give permissions to both the bucket itself and child objects
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10894488

  - Figured out if it was a permissions issue on S3 or a django-storages configuration issue
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13658829

  - `ListAllBuckets` has to be done in IAM user policy
- http://paltman.com/2007/09/21/detailed-amazon-s3-logging/

  - Once I setup logging, this post helped me decode the logs
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19425526

  - Apparently you can specify globs of permissions, which allowed me to test `s3:Delete*`, `s3:Put*`, and `s3:Get*` separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this has changed in recent years, but I was just able to collect static with the following permissions:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The permission that was tripping me up was the `PutObjectAcl`. I'm also not sure if the multipart stuff is necessary, but I don't want to find out its necessary for large files or something like that down the line.

Edit: Apparently django-storages will delete files in some situations. I was able to get it to work with:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There may be a couple extra fields here, but I'm having trouble reproducing a delete operation to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

putting permission policy aside, My issue was that i was creating bucket with root user. even though i provide access to IAM user for the bucket but still was getting `403 forbidden` then I create the bucket from IAM user by providing IAM user the console access. and it works out.