# Django collect static S3 An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I have created a S3 bucket for my Django static files. I am able to display the static files from S3 however when I run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command I get the error "An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden"

error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 338, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 248, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 469, in exists
    self.connection.meta.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=name)
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/john/Environments/PRM/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 719, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

base_settings.py

```
# aws settings
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
# s3 static settings
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your settings.py looks fine to me. The problem is with your AWS IAM policy. 403:Forbidden meaning that you do not have proper rights to access the S3 resources/collect static files to your root. You need to check AWS IAM user policy.
Unless I see your IAM user policy, can't say much.
in the mean time do check this link: [Looks similar to the problem you are facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134403/django-storages-boto-s3-minimal-credentials-for-collectstatic)